# O que é uma linguagem de programação hipotética?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem

Em um pequeno trecho de uma questão de concurso, mencionava sobre várias formas de representação de algoritmos e sobre linguagem de **programação hipotética**.

Qual seria a definição de uma linguagem de programação hipotética? É possível exemplificar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem grande chance de estar apenas se referindo a uma linguagem que não existe, cuja intenção do texto é não estabelecer sintaxe ou semântica específica de alguma linguagem existente, apenas exemplificar o problema em linhas gerais como seria em uma linguagem de programação não especificada.

O termo é usado sem um grande significado específico na computação, mas indica que é uma linguagem que só existe em teoria para efeitos de explicar algum conceito.

Um [Wikibook usando o termo](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming_Languages/Semantics_Specification). Alguns livros usam o termo:

- [Programming Language Explorations](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=NWcNDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=hypothetical%20programming%20language%20example&source=bl&ots=CoV3zh5Lj7&sig=M1XlRSCViIr1i0zKtSumK52uSmM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUqbXn-cHSAhXBE5AKHQQaDVo4ChDoAQgoMAU#v=onepage&q=hypothetical%20programming%20language%20example&f=false)
- [Introduction to Programming Languages](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=531cAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=hypothetical%20programming%20language%20example&source=bl&ots=oW-jLNXN_X&sig=1UOFZTl30G7fUAY9HfE6P2E5qds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW6oay-cHSAhXTnJAKHTEADwcQ6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=hypothetical%20programming%20language%20example&f=false)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).